# Filtering posts by custom field value not working

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, taxonomy

I have a custom post type called Location with a custom field called City.  I also have taxonomies on that post type called Specialties.  The specialty filter works just fine with the `tax_query`, but I can't get the custom field to filter.

This is not working, and neither is just about everything else I've been trying:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'location',
    'tax_query' => array(
          array(
          'taxonomy' => 'specialties',
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => $specialty,
        )),
    'meta_query' => array(array('city' => $location,'compare' => '=',))
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `'meta_query'` value is wrong - it should be:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'city',
        'value'   => $location,
        'compare' => '=',
    )
);
```

Anyway, you don't need to use `'meta_query'` in this case where you have to filter by just **one** meta field... So for a little more optimized code, try replacing your `$args` with the following:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'location',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'specialties',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $specialty,
        )
    ),
    'meta_key'  => 'city',
    'meta_value'=> $location,
);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm going to need to add one more field so probably need to get it working with 'meta_query'?  I tried this, and I get no results.

    $args = array('post_type' => 'location',
        'tax_query' => array(
              array(
              'taxonomy' => 'specialties',
              'field'    => 'slug',
              'terms'    => $specialty,
            )),
          'meta_query' => array(
            array(
              'key' => 'city',
              'value' => $location,
              'compare' => '=',
            ))
        );

Comment: @Von, if you have more than one field, then yes, you have to use `'meta_query'`... I check and recheck the `$args` in my answer and I can't find any error... If it doesn't work, I'd say it's because of the rest of your code. For example, ensure `$location` and `$specialty` holds a correct value, check your action hook, etc...

Comment: I couldn't make the custom field work in time so I just switched them all over to taxonomies and it worked like a charm.  Thanks for the help.